# Caffe: what is the difference between these 2 networks?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I am curious to know what is the difference between network 1 and 2? They both have conv with 16 filters.

Q: Are the 16 learned filters in 1 and 2 are different? Why? advantages/disadvantage of each?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

- the weights are the same (the `in_c`x16x3x3 kernel of conv16 is split into two `in_c`x8x3x3 kernels one for each of the conv8 layers),
- no `"Dropout"`

then the two nets compute the same output. However, I suspect that the first option is much more efficient (computing `im2col` only once, no need for copying/moving data around etc...)

However, when considering `"Dropout"`, the two alternatives are NOT equivalent anymore, as the dropout pattern for conv16 is the same for all 16 trained filters, the two conv8 see *different* dropout pattern during training and therefore likely to learn different kernels.

Comment: this is all true when training. but once the net is deployed, drop out has no effect: if the deployed weights are the same, then both alternatives behave the same (up to some computational overhead).